# Diferencia entre JDBC y JSON

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

Mi propósito es conectarme a una base da datos remota(MySQL) desde Android, hacer consultas, crear tablas y esas cositas básicas.

¿Que diferencia hay entre hacer una conexión usando el JDBC de Java, y usando JSON PHP o algo asi escuche?(Disculpen la ignorancia).

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tal y como está ahora la pregunta, no es clara. Parece que quieres saber la diferencia entre dos cosas, pero no sabes cuál es una de esas cosas. Deberías averiguar qué opciones son las que quieres comparar, investigar un poco online, y entonces hacer una pregunta más concreta.

Comment: En efecto, tal cual, sería el equivalente a preguntar la diferencia entre una manzana y un martillo. Claro que hay diferencias, pero no estamos siquiera hablando de 2 cosas dentro de la misma categoría.

Comment: En el posible escenario que planteas, desde Android _no te conectas a una  BD MySql_ sino que haces una llamada a una url remota que es la que se conecta a la BD. Son 2 cosas distintas. a) La conexión a la BD, que ocurre en el servidor,  generalmente vía PHP y que presenta los datos obtenidos generalmente en formato JSON. b) El uso que darás a esos datos recibidos del servidor en la app. O sea, en Android programas la app para que pida datos al servidor a través de una url y para que sepa manejar los datos recibidos. Otra cosa es que quieras tener los datos en local y no en un servidor remoto.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudado de mucho.
Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es mucho mas recomandable usar web services (restful o soap) y por lo general en cuestion a aplicaciones moviles se usa mayormente estos servicios y muy raro realizar una conexion directa entre app y db remoto.

y cual es la diferencia:

**JDBC de Java**: Realiza una conexion directa a tu base de datos de app a base de datos.

**Web Service**: Realiza una peticion a tu servicio creado y te devuelve la informacion solicitada sin tener acceso directo a la base de datos, la conexion o la consulta a la base de datos de la informacion que solicitaste la realiza tu servicio.